Recommendations on 3D software for recreating human vantage point of satellites, planets, and star positions from fixed time, altitude, and lat/long
I have a few videos of (seemingly) anomalous objects taken from the cockpit of a commercial airliner in the past few days.  I know the copilot very well.  This person is staunch skeptic on the topic of UAPs, UFOs, etc. but is 100% convinced that the objects observed (and filmed by both pilot and copilot phone cameras) were not satellites, aircrafts, or weather balloons.  This pilot has been flying for decades and is also a military pilot and a very credible observer.  My best guess is that what they saw were several different satellites or perhaps high altitude balloons on different trajectories that were catching sun rays from over the horizon.  I know the exact latlong, altitude, speed, and heading of the flight during these videos.  I would like to recreate that information in a 3D satellite tracker that would allow me to simulate their view from the cockpit at that time to see if anything lines up that could explain what is recorded on video.
Does anyone know of any software that would allow me to do this?
I'm not looking to solve the observation on this message board, simply asking about software recommendations.  It would also be helpful if astronomical information were shown in this software, too, so I can also check star/planet locations at the time.  Thanks!

Satellites' orbits change over time, unless they are very recent videos you might run in to an issue of finding the orbital data for the dates in question.  But Stellarium, Heavens-Above.com, and Sky Safari all do what you ask.

Thank you!  I will check them out!  The videos are less than a week old.

...is 100% convinced... It has been my experience that no matter how much evidence you provide, people with such certainty won't accept it as enough.   Note also that cockpits have lots of potential for reflections and distortions.  You'll find that nearly impossible to allow for the effect of.

What is the relevance of the to astronomy?

There are more options in the meta question Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them? but Heavens-Above usually does the job.
Even in low Earth orbit, satellites are already literally at a million feet or more of elevation, so for identification purposes you do not need special software to address flight altitude.
